# VB.NET How to fill this textbox on a webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, textbox, fill

Trying to fill this text box in a webbrowser programmatically.

```
<div class="chatmsgwrapper"><textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="chatmsg "></textarea></div>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work at all...

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("chatmsgwrapper")
        If element.GetAttribute("class") = "chatmsg " Then
            element.SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `chatmsgwrapper` is class name, not tag name. 

You have html tag `textarea`.

 You can get attribute "classname" (not "class"), then set value.

Here is working example tested on VB2010:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
    If element.GetAttribute("classname") = "chatmsg " Then
            element.SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetElementsByTagName()` won't retrieve an HTML element by class name.  Your tag name is `textarea`.

Try the following...

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
        If element.GetAttribute("class") = "chatmsg " Then
            element.SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You were close to solve it. Thank you for your help!